# Overload operator << for enumerated member of a class in member functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

How do I overload the << operator for enums that are members of a class. Specifically, I have the following code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace foo {
    class bar {
    public:
        enum a { b, c, d};

        static void print() {
            cout << b << endl;
        }
    };

    ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, bar::a var) {

        switch (var) {
        case bar::b:
            return os << "b";
        case bar::c:
            return os << "c";
        case bar::d:
            return os << "d";
        }
        return os;
    }


}
int main() {
    foo::bar::print();

    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the print function to print "b" instead of "1"?

Comment: Try making sure a declaration of your `operator<<` overload is visible before the definition of `foo::bar::print()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace foo {

    class bar {
    public:
        enum a { b, c, d};

        static void print();
    };

    ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, bar::a var) {

        switch (var) {
        case bar::b:
            return os << "b";
        case bar::c:
            return os << "c";
        case bar::d:
            return os << "d";
        }
        return os;
    }


    void bar::print() {
        cout << b << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    foo::bar::print();

    return 0;
}
```

[EDIT] As previously stated by aschepler, you only need to ensure that `operator<<(ostream &, bar::a)` is visible before the definition of `bar::print`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class bar {
public:
    enum a { b = 'b', c = 'c', d = 'd' };

    static void print() {
        cout << char(b) << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Clever. I like that. But print may not be the only place that wants to print the enum.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your use of `cout << bar::` comes *before* your `ostream<< bar::` overload is declared, so it's not calling your overload. Move the definition down.

```
class bar {
public:
   enum a { b, c, d };
   static void print();
};

ostream& operator<<  (ostream& os, bar::a var) {
   ...

void bar::print()
{
   cout << b << endl;
}
```

EDIT: I see some else posted that while I was typing this.